# Sql create correct query for select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table notes. There are column 'tags' (varchar(255) ) . For example, data is:

```
1)Content='Note1', tags='18,20' 
2)Content='Note2', tags='18',
3)Content='Note3', tags='45',
4)Content='Note4', tags='118,75'
```

I need write sql for select all rows with tags '18', so result must be like this:

```
1)Content='Note1', tags='18,20' 
2)Content='Note2', tags='18',
```

I tried write sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE tags LIKE ('%18%')
```

But result is wrong:

```
1)Content='Note1', tags='18,20' 
2)Content='Note2', tags='18',
4)Content='Note4', tags='118,75'
```

How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET` function

```
 SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('18', tags );
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to create your own `SPLIT function` and use it instead of `LIKE`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21191752)

Comment: @IanKenney Why doesn't this answer the question. It is an answer (Although a bit low quality). These types of answers, should not be deleted through the VLQ queue, and should be downvoted instead.

Comment: @FankerZ This would be better suited as a comment to the original question.  An answer may include some example SQL in this case